# Avoid Task.Run to run the same method two times at the same time

Tags: c#, asynchronous

I'm trying to use `Task.Run` to send some data to a serveur while doing something else, and in fact it works.
The problem is that in some circumstances, it can be called two times in just a few milliseconds and it creates bugs.
So, what is the best way to avoid that ?

The code I'm using:

```
Task.Run(async () =>
        {
            PostValues();               
        });
```

Comment: "It can be called two times in just few miliseconds and it creates bugs". How so? What kind of bugs? You should be more specific ...

Answer (score 0):

Maintain a dictionary of the tasks you've started (by giving them a name) and remove them when the task is completed. The dictionary should be thread safe (so not the built-in Dictionary class, but TDictionary from http://www.philippiercedeveloper.com/wp-content/uploads/2009/08/Threaded.zip

The resulting code would look like this;

```
TDictionary<string, DateTime> runningCode = new TDictionary<string,DateTime>();

...

    if(runningCode.AddIfNotExists("MyCodeDescriptor", DateTime.Now()))
    {
       Task.Run(async() => 
       {
           PostValues();
           runningCode.Remove("MyCodeDescriptor");
       });
    }
```

This means you will need to have some kind of monikor for the code you want to execute, so that you can uniquely identify it. I've used "MyCodeDescriptor" but it could be any string that describes the unique block of code.

Comment: I can't download your THreaded.zip, but can't I use ArrayList or ConcurrentDictionary instead ?

Comment: After some tests, it seems that a simple `lock` around the whole function content does the job.